# Using QCoreApplication::setEventFilter() in qt

Tags: qt

I want to catch all events for the application. How can i use this method to achive this?
Please help me !!

Answer (score 2):

QCoreApplication inherits QObject, so you can call QCoreApplication::installEventFilter(QObject*). For further reference about event filters, see [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

Comment: With this implementation I am facing a problem... I want to just monitor all Mouseclicks, but if a subclass handling 'MouseClick' then that event message is not handled in eventFilter(). Can you help me to understand this functionality.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement and provide a function and point to it.

For example:

```
bool myEventFilter(void *message, long *result)
{
  // do something with message and result
}
```

And call it like this:

```
app->setEventFilter( myEventFilter );
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but with this implemention i am not able to catch any Event other than timer.

Comment: According to the documentation http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#setEventFilter it should catch all events. I haven't tried it out properly though.